# AWS Step Functions - abort one Map iteration from another

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a State Machine with a few inline Map iterations that wait for a task token. Only one of the iterations will resume and complete while others will hang waiting. How can the winning iteration abort the no longer relevant ones so the Map step could exit and the State Machine execution continue with just the result of the winning iteration?

Comment: I doubt that is possible - that does not sound like a reasonable setup to begin with. Why do the other executions hang?

Comment: They all send a message to a different recipient and wait for a callback with a result. Some results make others irrelevant so no need to wait for them. For example voting that requires unanimous"yes". If one callback is a "yes" then we wait for the others but if it's a "no" then other votes are irrelevant and won't probably be even cast. Or may be an action with a "Buy now" price - if the bet is under we wait for higher bets, if it's at we have the winner. I see many reasonable cases like this for a sate machine. Just asking if AWS Step Functions is capable of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I admit it's awkward, you can implement this "First Finisher Wins" pattern using a [Fail State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-fail-state.html) in your Item Processor and [Catch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-fallback-states) on the [Map State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html). For Inline Map, when one iteration fails, it will cause the overall Map State to Fail and it will abort the incomplete branches.

See the example below which illustrates this. In this case, the first pass state generates an Array of 11 items and passes that into the Map state. 10 of these will wait for 100 seconds. 1 of them will wait for 5 seconds, then fail with a specific Cause. The Map State Catch recognizes this and sends the workflow execution to the next state to continue.

One thing missing from this is that you won't get the result from that "winning" iteration (because Fail states can't pass dynamic data). So if you need that, you'd need to do something like store that result in a DynamoDB (maybe keyed by the execution id) to read in after.

```
{
  "StartAt": "Generate List",
  "States": {
    "Generate List": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "input_array.$": "States.ArrayRange(0,10,1)"
      },
      "Next": "Map"
    },
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemProcessor": {
        "ProcessorConfig": {
          "Mode": "INLINE"
        },
        "StartAt": "Choice",
        "States": {
          "Choice": {
            "Type": "Choice",
            "Choices": [
              {
                "Variable": "$",
                "NumericEquals": 0,
                "Next": "Wait 5 Seconds"
              }
            ],
            "Default": "Wait 100 Seconds"
          },
          "Wait 5 Seconds": {
            "Type": "Wait",
            "Seconds": 5,
            "Next": "Fail"
          },
          "Fail": {
            "Type": "Fail",
            "Error": "MapStateEarlyAbort"
          },
          "Wait 100 Seconds": {
            "Type": "Wait",
            "Seconds": 100,
            "Next": "Success"
          },
          "Success": {
            "Type": "Succeed"
          }
        }
      },
      "ItemsPath": "$.input_array",
      "Next": "Keep Going",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "MapStateEarlyAbort"
          ],
          "Next": "Keep Going"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Keep Going": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will work but indeed is not the prettiest. I already save task tokens so if I have to have custom code for this either way, might as well just send task success to the loosing iterations and send them gracefully to an End: true step via a Choice. Which was the plan in case no better options. Good to confirm, thanks Justin.